# Get visible text from webview in android

Tags: java, android, html, webview

How to get only visible text from webview?

I have tried this:-

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
    new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
       Log.d("HTML", html);

     }
   });
```

But i get html string. I only need text content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get innerText instead of innerHtml:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerText
```